# Highest possible sum across 2D array

Tags: algorithm

What is the best way to find the highest possible sum across a 2D integer array? You can't repeat columns and rows. Eg.

```
1 3 6
4 5 2
3 1 3
Max sum: 3+5+6=14
```

I know there is a method called the Hungarian algorithm, but that seems to be more suitable for finding minimum sum.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what elements do you include in the sum? Do they have to be contiguous? Do you select entire column or row?

Comment: Amended to clarify.

Comment: Best way I can think of is dynamic programming. For example -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621337/java-maximum-sum-in-path-through-a-2d-array

Comment: @user3918985 Why not just negate the values and apply Hungarian Algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the hungarian algorithm.

You need to modify the search criteria to look for largest sum instead of the smallest on. You also need to run Bellman-Ford instead of Dijkstra for the search component (because Dijkstra can't compute maximum sum path).

You can't run into a constantly increasing loop because the selected nodes are already paired using their maximum value, so any change would yield a lower total sum. The algorithm will chose to rearrange the connections if the loss from the already connected nodes is less than the gain from the newly connected one. You don't need to worry about it.