# Max sum path in 2D array + double two values to achieve better score

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array and I need to find the max sum path that can be collected by **left bottom and going only top and right until reach an end**. I have done it on Java (task very similar to **[Project Euler: Problem 81](https://projecteuler.net/problem=81)**):

```
static int maxSumPath(int[][] data) {
    final int length = data.length;

    final int[][] sumArr = new int[length][length];

    for (int row = length - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
        for (int col = 0; col < length; col++) {
            if (row == length - 1 && col == 0) {
                sumArr[row][col] = data[row][col];
            } else if (row == length - 1) {
                sumArr[row][col] = sumArr[row][col - 1] + data[row][col];
            } else if (col == 0) {
                sumArr[row][col] = sumArr[row + 1][col] + data[row][col];
            } else {
                sumArr[row][col] = Math.max(sumArr[row][col - 1], sumArr[row + 1][col]) + data[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    return sumArr[0][length - 1];
}
```

Example

> **3**, **0**, **2**
>
> **2**, 0, 0
>
> **0**, 3, 0

Result **7**.

But now I need to implement opportunity **to double any value of that array to achieve better score and I can do it only twice and double certain value only once**.

Example (in this matrix numbers with `*` must be doubled)

> **3***, **0**, **2**
>
> **2***, 0, 0
>
> **0***, 3, 0

Result **12**.

Comment: The first part looks like seam carving with some restrictions, i.e. go up and right. In seam carving, you are creating energy array by using dynamic programming. The second part is to choose top 2 values and double them(did I misunderstand this part?)

Comment: @smttsp **Second part is choose 2 biggest values while walking by *max sum path* and double them**

Comment: can you provide another example, your array can be 3x3 or can be any nxm?

Comment: @YCF_L The issue is write algorithm for square matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a third dimension to your 2-D array, with exactly three layers:

```
final int[][][] sumArr = new int[3][length][length]
```

- Layer zero represents the best sum you can get without doubling any elements
- Layer one represents the best sum you can get with doubling only one number
- Layer two represents the best sum you can get with doubling two numbers

The algorithm is a simple extension of what you already have, except now you need to set three partial sums in each branch of your `if` condition.

Here is your code modified according to the above:

```
static int maxSumPath(int[][] data) {
    final int length = data.length;
    final int[][][] sumArr = new int[3][length][length];
    for (int row = length - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
        for (int col = 0; col < length; col++) {
            int val = data[row][col];
            int val2 = data[row][col] * 2;
            if (row == length - 1 && col == 0) {
                sumArr[0][row][col] = val;
                sumArr[1][row][col] = val2;
            } else if (row == length - 1) {
                sumArr[0][row][col] = sumArr[0][row][col - 1] + val;
                sumArr[1][row][col] = Math.max(
                    sumArr[1][row][col - 1] + val
                ,   sumArr[0][row][col - 1] + val2
                );
                sumArr[2][row][col] = Math.max(
                    sumArr[1][row][col - 1] + val2
                ,   sumArr[2][row][col - 1] + val
                );
            } else if (col == 0) {
                sumArr[0][row][col] = sumArr[0][row + 1][col] + val;
                sumArr[1][row][col] = Math.max(
                    sumArr[0][row + 1][col] + val2
                ,   sumArr[1][row + 1][col] + val
                );
                sumArr[2][row][col] = Math.max(
                    sumArr[1][row + 1][col] + val2
                ,   sumArr[2][row + 1][col] + val
                );
            } else {
                sumArr[0][row][col] = Math.max(
                    sumArr[0][row][col - 1], sumArr[0][row + 1][col]
                ) + data[row][col];
                sumArr[1][row][col] = Math.max(
                    Math.max(sumArr[0][row][col - 1], sumArr[0][row + 1][col]) + val2
                ,   Math.max(sumArr[1][row][col - 1], sumArr[1][row + 1][col]) + val
                );
                sumArr[2][row][col] = Math.max(
                    Math.max(sumArr[1][row][col - 1], sumArr[1][row + 1][col])+val2
                ,   Math.max(sumArr[2][row][col - 1], sumArr[2][row + 1][col])+val
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return sumArr[2][0][length - 1];
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/GBu9DV)

Comment: *"Layer one represents the best sum you can get with doubling only one number"* how to know what value to double ?

Comment: I have to collect 3d **[array like this](https://gist.github.com/dozortsev/8b67026e3082efff7f54d22ffe0dfdfd)** but how should I know what value to double while loop ?

Comment: @AntonDozortsev You try to double each value that you see. Prior sums in layer zero are constructed in such a way that you know that you haven't doubled any values so far. Hence, you double the current value, and write it into layer one at the same row/col. Then you do the same for layer one to layer two, adding double the current value to the best prior sum from layer one. Once you are done, the best result is in the layer two for the top right corner.

Comment: Are you sure that final score in layer two for the top right corner for above matrix will be **12** ?

Comment: @AntonDozortsev Та нема за що! Завжди радий допомогти.