# Finding the Shortest Path in a 2D Integer Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, shortest-path, dijkstra, a-star

I am making a snake game where the snake crosses through a 2D int array as its terrain. The values stored in the 2D array represent the time in seconds it takes to cross.

For example,

```
int[][] MAP = { 
    { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 },
    { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 },
    { 3, 2, 2, 3, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 3, 2, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 3, 2, 1 }
 };
```

So going from `map[0][0]` to `map[0][4]` takes `1 + 1 + 2 + 2` seconds. How would I make an algorithm that would find the shortest possible path for a snake to travel from position `map[startX][startY]` to `map[endX][endY]`?

This isn't a homework assignment, I'm just making a game for fun and would like to learn how to do this.

Comment: Seems easy enough using brute force with best path yet pruning, implemented with recursion. What have your tried and where is the problem?

Comment: You should look into A* pathfinding.

Comment: I looked at the A* algorithm but I couldn't find any solution where they used different values as array positions. Most of the solutions only had 1's and 0's.

Comment: This is apparently more a matter of convention; if you have weights on the nodes instead of the edges, you could suppose that all in-edges of a node have the weight of the node.

Comment: A good A* pathfinding video: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySN5Wnu88nE&t=361s)

Answer (score 0):

This is one is kinda known problem when discussing "dynamic programming", and even resembles an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621337/java-maximum-sum-in-path-through-a-2d-array).

Still, I didn't find a solution that also prints the shortest path, so:

```
public class FastestPathCalculator {

    private final int[][] map;

    public FastestPathCalculator(int[][] map) {
        this.map=map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] map = new int[][]{
                {1, 1, 1, 4, 2},
                {1, 2, 5, 2, 2},
                {3, 2, 2, 3, 1},
                {1, 1, 3, 2, 1},
                {3, 1, 3, 2, 1}
        };

        FastestPathCalculator c = new FastestPathCalculator(map);
        boolean[] result = c.computeFastestPath(map);
        c.printPath(result);
    }
```

Here, the boolean array represents the steps taken from (0,0) to (4,4). A value of TRUE means the step is to the right, FALSE means go down.
In this example, the array has 8 cells.

```
    public boolean[] computeFastestPath(int[][] map) {
        int pathLength = map.length + map[0].length - 2;
        boolean[] result = new boolean[pathLength];

        int[][] mapOfMinimalSums = buildMapOfMinimalSums();

        int x = map.length-1;
        int y = map[0].length-1;

        for (int i = pathLength - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (x == 0)
                result[i] = true;
            else if (y == 0)
                result[i] = false;
            else if (mapOfMinimalSums[x][y] == map[x][y] + mapOfMinimalSums[x][y-1]) {
                result[i] = true;
                y--;
            }
            else {
                result[i] = false;
                x--;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void printPath(boolean[] result) {
        String[][] newPath = new String[map.length][map[0].length];
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        newPath[x][y] = String.valueOf(map[x][y]);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i]) {
                y++;
            } else {
                x++;
            }
            newPath[x][y] = String.valueOf(map[x][y]);
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < map[0].length; j++) {
                if (newPath[i][j] == null) {
                    System.out.print(" , ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(newPath[i][j] + ", ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private int[][] buildMapOfMinimalSums() {
        int[][] mapOfSums = new int[map.length][map[0].length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < map[0].length; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                    mapOfSums[i][j] = map[i][j];
                else if (i == 0) {
                    mapOfSums[i][j] = mapOfSums[i][j - 1] + map[i][j];
                }
                else if (j == 0)
                    mapOfSums[i][j] = mapOfSums[i-1][j] + map[i][j];
                else
                    mapOfSums[i][j] = Math.min(mapOfSums[i-1][j], mapOfSums[i][j-1]) + map[i][j];
            }
        }
        return mapOfSums;
    }
}
```